# "Only hand luggage is included"

Tags: luggage, hand-luggage, british-airways

I'm travelling with British Airways from Zurich to London City Airport, and my ticket says "Only hand luggage is included in the ticket". Now, according to the British Airways website  hand baggage includes a cabin bag and a personal bag; I'm however somewhat confused by the wording - does this mean I can bring a backpack and a small bag?

I'm also concerned about this:

> If you are travelling on a UK Domestic or European shorthaul flight, to and from London, you can travel light and make a quick getaway with our hand baggage only fares. These don't include a checked baggage allowance but everything else is covered by the great-value price, including free online check-in, allocated seats, the same generous hand baggage allowance, and refreshments on board

Sorry if this is an obvious question, it's my first time traveling.

Comment: Hand Baggage only flights with british airways you are allowed 1 laptop bag or purse which can go below your seat + you are also allowed one hand luggage which you can put in the overhead locker.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

BA "Hand Luggage Only" fares are ones without any checked baggage allowance. You still get all the cabin baggage allowance of a normal ticket, it just means you can't check in a bag (without an extra fee)

You can find all the info on the [BA Baggage Policy on their website](http://www.britishairways.com/en-gb/information/baggage-essentials?source=MNVINF3baggage_essentials&link=main_nav), under [Hand Baggage Allowance](http://www.britishairways.com/en-gb/information/baggage-essentials/hand-baggage-allowances). You're allowed 1 cabin bag, and one personal bag.

The cabin bag is limited to 56cm x 45cm x 25cm (22in x 18in x 10in) including handles, pockets and wheels.

The personal bag (normally intended to be a laptop bag, briefcase or large handbag) is limited to 45cm x 36cm x 20cm (18in x 14in x 8in) including handles, pockets and wheels. This normally has to go under the seat in front of you

So, small rucksack and small bag is fine!